# Presenting dynamic information from CSV file

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, csv, dynamic

So, i have googled and googled and googled. Maybe I need to improve my google skills.
Maybe the answer already exists somewhere on this page but I have not found it. Anyway.

So I am dealing with a csv file which shows date, transacation category, location and the amount of the transaction. In that order.

So what I need to do is to present this information dynamically in an HTML table. The user should be able to select the location from a dropdown menu and the table should be updated with the corresponding information about transactions done from that location.

I am able to present the overall information from the csv file, but when making it truly dynamical Im struggeling.

So I have the information stored in a 2d array [date, transaction category, location, transaction category].

So my real problem is, how do I make this truly dynamical. Meaning, how can I update the  tag with  without hardcoding anything. I want it to be independet of what csv file I am uploading.

I'm thinking that it would be good to have a function that loop through the array and split out the user selected array on an onchange event and then send the selecte array to output. But I cant quite imagined exactly how this would be done...

Thankfull for any suggestions. :)

Comment: Did you have a look on front-end frameworks like VueJS or Angular ? They could help you a lot into easily loading data (as csv files for examples) and presenting data with filtering and sorting capabilities

Comment: Thanks for the idea! I will definatley look into them. As It's a introductionary course at the uni they want us to use javascript without extra libaries so I think I will have to stick with some more basic stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I would turn it into JSON first and go from there. One of my favorite parsers is [csvtojson](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csvtojson). It's pretty simple to use.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. They told us the assignment would be to easy to solve with JSON so unfortunatley I cant use that :( but will look into it for the future.

Comment: @bjorn90 you should look into ways to do it with node's built in filesystem. You can read it line by line and convert it to whatever you would like